# Inconsistent querying using cypher, neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have come across a very strange problem with my data and cypher.

I run this query

```
match (sm:Small)-->(a:Activity) return distinct a
```

and it returns all 7 a nodes that exist that are connected to Small's (which is also all of them).

I run this query

```
match (a:Activity) return distinct a
```

And it returns only 1 of the a nodes that exists

If I run (same as first one except no direction)

```
match (sm:Small)--(a:Activity) return distinct a
```

I also only get one single Activity node

The one activity node was that always shows up was initially added to the database first. The other ones that are missing, were added later in a separate query.

If I run a query in the browser that returns all of them and there outgoing relationships to Small nodes the visualization of them all looks the same and proper.

Is there anyway to further interrogate this?

Comment: Do you have a script to build your data set?

Comment: Might be useful to return the id(a) to see exactly what is being returned in each of the queries... chances are it's not actually the same "a" ...

Comment: Which version of the database are you using? Can you perhaps share your db?